# Reglas de seguridad firebase firestore para subcolecciones

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

estoy creando una app donde, explicado a groso modo, los usuarios se crean una cuenta, la cual se vincula con un documento de firestore, al que suben y leen datos. Estos documentos también contienen subcolecciones de datos.
[image: Estructura de documentos]

[image: Estructura de subcolecciones]

La colección coach y users tienen estructuras casi iguales pero con diferentes tipos de datos.

1. Quiero que solo cada usuario autenticado pueda leer y escribir datos en su cuenta, tanto en colecciones como subcolecciones.
2. También me gustaría que, si un usuario añade el email de un coach en el campo "coach", este coach pudiera leer (exclusivamente) todo el documento del usuario que le ha dado permiso. Es decir: hola@gml.com añade a coach@g.com en su campo "coach", por lo que coach@g.com podrá leer la información de hola@gml.com

He probado multiples maneras para el apartado 1:
[image: Reglas 1]

Con esto conseguía leer cualquier documento users si el usuario esta autenticado, pero no las subcolecciones.
El apartado 2 no se como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

El contenido del documento que consultas está en el objeto [resource.data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation). Por ejemplo para leer el email del coach debes escribir `resource.data.coach`. Ahora si quieres acceder a un documento que no sea el que se está consultando, debes usar el método [get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

```
match /users/{email} {
    allow create: if request.auth != null;
    allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email in [email, resource.data.coach];
}
match /users/{email}/{subCollections=**} {
    allow create: if request.auth != null;
    allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email in [
        email,
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(email)).data.coach
    ];
}
```

Comment: No funciona, tengo el mismo problema que con anteriores que había probado, al intentar leer las subcolecciones me lanza un error. Tampoco me funciona lo que he denominado como apartado dos, me sale la lista vacía, cosa que no pasa cuando permito todas las operaciones. Gracias